# Select by a key for all associated records from a denormalizing database

Tags: sql, sql-server, denormalization

I am using SQL server 2012. I just have access to a database that does not have any relationships yet. I don't know much about SQL script. I want to see all the records that associate to EmployeeID 102 from all tables that have column EmployeeID. E.g.

```
EmployeeID    LastName     FirstName   (from table Employees)
102           Jonh         Smith
EmployeeID    HireDate                 (from table EmploymentRecords)
102           2/1/2014
EmployeeID    Monthly Salary           (from table Salary)
102           2000
and so on
```

I tried the following script, but the Result window become closed and on Message window it just said "Command(s) completed successfully". How can I get the above results. Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE tnames_cursor CURSOR
FOR
  SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
OPEN tnames_cursor
DECLARE @tablename sysname
FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename

if (select count(*) from information_schema.columns where  table_name = @tablename and     Column_name ='EmployeeID') > 0

BEGIN   

  SELECT @tablename = RTRIM(@tablename) 
  EXEC ('SELECT *  FROM '+ @tablename +'where  EmployeeID = 102')
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement will probably prevent everything from working:

```
EXEC ('SELECT *  FROM '+ @tablename +'where  EmployeeID = 102')
```

You need a space after the table name:

```
EXEC ('SELECT *  FROM '+ @tablename +' where  EmployeeID = 102')
```

In addition, your cursor logic seems off.  You should be checking for `@@FETCH_STATUS` and then closing and deallocating the cursor.

Follow the example at the end of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the immediate problem is that you are not looping through the whole result set.

```
DECLARE tnames_cursor CURSOR
FOR
  SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
OPEN tnames_cursor
DECLARE @tablename sysname
FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

    if (select count(*) from information_schema.columns where  table_name = @tablename and     Column_name ='EmployeeID') > 0
    begin

        SELECT @tablename = RTRIM(@tablename) 
        EXEC ('SELECT *  FROM '+ @tablename +'where  EmployeeID = 102')
    end


    FETCH NEXT FROM tnames_cursor INTO @tablename
end
close tnames_cursor
deallocate tnames_cursor
```